# Methods to create deep copy of objects without the help of Marshal

Tags: ruby, oop, clone, deep-copy

I have 3 simple classes CashRegister, Bill and Position. A CashRegister is composed of Bill objects and a Bill object is composed of Position objects. They're implemented as followed

```
class CashRegister
  def initialize
    @bills = []
  end

  def clone 
    #?
  end
end

class Bill
  def initialize(nr)
    @nr = nr
    @positions = []
  end

  def clone 
    #?
  end
end

class Position
  def initialize(product, price)
    @product = product
    @price = price
  end

  def clone 
    #?
  end
end
```

How do I create methods that can deep copy the objects of these classes. The use of `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(an_obj))` is not allowed.

Edit: So far I've got this:

```
    class CashRegister
      def initialize
        @bills = []
      end

      def clone 
        @bills.map { |bill| bill.clone}
      end
    end

    class Bill
      def initialize(nr)
        @nr = nr
        @positions = []
      end

      def clone 
        cloned = super
        cloned.positions = @positions.map{ |pos| pos.clone}      
        cloned
      end
    end

    class Position

      attr_reader :preis
      # this method is given
      def produkt
        @produkt.clone()
      end

      def initialize(product, price)
        @product = product
        @price = price
      end

      def clone 
        cloned = super
        cloned.product    
        cloned
      end
    end
```

The clone method in class Position seems to be ok (no compile error). But there is an error in the one in class Bill, it says "undefined method 'positions=', so the problem must be in the line `cloned.positions = @positions.map{ |pos| pos.clone}`. But I don't understand, can't we call `cloned.positions` like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works

```
class CashRegister
  attr_accessor :bills      

  def initialize
    @bills = []
  end

  def clone 
    cloned = super
    cloned.bills = @bills.map { |bill| bill.clone }
    cloned 
  end
end

class Bill
  attr_accessor :positions

  def initialize(nr)
    @nr = nr
    @positions = []
  end

  def clone 
    cloned = super
    cloned.positions = @positions.map{ |pos| pos.clone }      
    cloned
  end
end

class Position
  attr_reader :price
  attr_writer :product

  # this method is given
  def product
    @product.clone
  end

  def initialize(product, price)
    @product = product
    @price = price
  end

  def clone 
    cloned = super
    cloned.product = product  
    cloned
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just the instance variables you have to worry about.

```
class Position
  attr_accessor :product, :price
  def initialize(product, price)
    @product = product
    @price = price
  end
end

p1 = Position.new("lima beans", 2.31)
  #=> #<Position:0x000000027587b0 @product="lima beans", @price=2.31>
p2 = Position.new(p1.product, p1.price)
  #=> #<Position:0x0000000273dd48 @product="lima beans", @price=2.31>
```

We can confirm that `p2` is a deep copy of `p1`.

```
p1.product = "lettuce"
p1.price   = 1.49

p1 #=> #<Position:0x0000000271f870 @product="lettuce", @price=1.49>
p2 #=> #<Position:0x000000026e9e00 @product="lima beans", @price=2.31>

p2.product = "spinach"
p2.price = 2.10

p1 #=> #<Position:0x0000000271f870 @product="lettuce", @price=1.49>
p2 #=> #<Position:0x000000026e9e00 @product="spinach", @price=2.1>
```

It's more complex if, for example, the class were defined as follows (where `products` is an array).

```
p1 = Position.new ["carrots", "onions"]
  #=> #<Position:0x000000025b8928 @products=["carrots", "onions"]>
p2 = Position.new p1.products
  #=> #<Position:0x000000025b0048 @products=["carrots", "onions"]>

p1.products << "beets"

p1 #=> #<Position:0x000000025b8928 @products=["carrots", "onions", "beets"]>
p2 #=> #<Position:0x000000025b0048 @products=["carrots", "onions", "beets"]>
```

`p2` is not what we want. We would need to write

```
p1 = Position.new ["carrots", "onions"]
  #=> #<Position:0x00000002450900 @products=["carrots", "onions"]>
p2 = Position.new p1.products.dup
  #=> #<Position:0x0000000243aa88 @products=["carrots", "onions"]>
```

(note the `.dup`) so that

```
p1.products << "beets"
  #=> ["carrots", "onions", "beets"]

p1 #=> #<Position:0x00000002450900 @products=["carrots", "onions", "beets"]>
p2 #=> #<Position:0x0000000243aa88 @products=["carrots", "onions"]>
```

More generally, we need to make deep copies of the instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer is to use the full_dup gem (full disclosure, written by me) then simply use:

```
p2 = p1.full_dup
```

Now full_dup, like regular dup, does not copy any singleton methods. If that is important, try the full_clone gem (yup, by me too) instead.

If there are fields that need to excluded from the dup (or clone process), the optional full_dup_exclude (or full_clone_exclude) method can be defined to list fields to be excluded from processing.

Note there is no need to worry about trying to clone numbers, symbols, and other non-clonable things that may exist in your object. These are handled safely be the gems.